# Java program for counting the most frequent elements

Tags: java

I want a java program to count the most frequent elements in a file

Comment: Have you initialized `parser`?

Comment: i am calling parser from this class:

Comment: And what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: But, where have you initialized it?

Comment: As it is, `parser` will be `null`. Remove that (useless) line or use `this.parser.readLines()` if there is a class variable of the same name. Or probably you need `Parser parser = new Parser()` instead.

Comment: Zabri I have it here: the put method is underlined: topN.put(entry.getKey(), newCount);

Comment: Ajai you can see am calling it from the Parser class

Comment: It seems there are at least two errors: the uninitialized parser (which you will probably find the first time you run the program) and the type error with the map (which your IDE or compiler can detect).

Comment: tobias_k i have tried both suggestions but they dident work out

Comment: It might be best if you described your algorithm in english, so we understand the intent. The current bug you're stumbling on is clearly about `put`ting the wrong type into a `Map`, but i think other things will shake out once you're past that.

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem that your "newCount" is a `String` instead of an `Integer`?

```
        String newCount = entry.getValue().toString();
        if(topN.containsKey(entry.getKey())){
            newCount += topN.get(entry.getKey());
        }
```

Comment: It shouldn't be an `Integer`; it should be an `Actor`, according to the map definition - but this would be why the `put`'s throwing an error.

Comment: oh, goodness, yes. Thanks, @SpacePope ! Honestly, i'm not quite sure what any of the types *should* be... shouldn't the parser read actors and sketches (both strings, maybe?) and then loop over that to update a map of actors and counts (string + integer), then take the top N entries in that map, when sorted by value?

Comment: Yeah...for some questions on SO, you can only be reasonably expected to address one problem at a time. :)

Answer (score 0):

With the line `Parser parser;` you declare a variable of your class `Parser`, but you do not initialize that varialbe. Use `Parser parser = new Parser();` instead.

There also seem to be a whole lot of type problem along the lines of

```
String newCount = entry.getValue().toString();
if(topN.containsKey(entry.getKey())){
    newCount += topN.get(entry.getKey());
}
topN.put(entry.getKey(), newCount);
```

It seems like you want to add up the counts, but this will not work if you convert the `Integer` to `String` first! Also, the `key` of the `Entry` will be a value, so `topN` can never contain that key, as it is a `Map` of `Strings` and `Actors`, and even if it would, how would you add an `Actor` to an `Integer` (or `String`)? Finally, as others have noted, the `put` will fail, as both the type of the key and the value do not match the types of the `Map`.

WIthout knowing what those other classes (`Sketch`, `Value`, `Actor`, etc.) do, it is very hard do give clear advice how to fix your problem.

Comment: i dont think i will have space for all the codes and now am getting code formatting error to post all the relevant classes

Comment: No need to post all the classes, just describe what they do. Particularly, what is `Sketch` and `Value` and what's their relation to `Actor`?

Comment: public class ApproxCount<Value>. The Value is generic. Sketch is an inner class for ApproCount

Answer (score 0):

`topN` is declared as `Map<String, Actor>`. So key must be a `String` and value must be of type `Actor`.

In `topN.put(entry.getKey(), newCount);`, `newCount` (a String) is not an `Actor`. Also check if `entry.getKey()` is a String.

```
public class Parser {

        private BufferedReader bf;
        private static final String ACTOR_MOVIE_FILE = "actormovie.txt";
        private Map<String, Actor> actors;

        //this is the input file size
        int fileSize = ACTOR_MOVIE_FILE.length();

        public Parser() {
                try {
                        bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ACTOR_MOVIE_FILE), 32768);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "file cannot be located ", "File not found exception", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                actors = new Hashtable<String, Actor>(1713251);
        }

        /**
         * this reads data on a line one at a time
         * @return actors in the hash table, with the name of an actor as a,
         * and value as the actor object
         */
        public Map<String, Actor> readLines() {
                 String line=" ";

                while(true){
                        try {
                                line = bf.readLine();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "deadlock file not in proper format", "we have error reading the file", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }

                        if(line == null){ 
                            break; 
                            }

                        String[] tokens = line.split("/");        
                        assemblyLines(tokens);
                }
                try { 
                    bf.close(); 

                } catch(IOException e){

                }
                return actors;
        }

        /**
         * from a line we get stringTokenizers parse to the data structures. Film is described as a
         * stringTokenizer with film object created from it. There are actors which are as well 
         * stringTokenizers created as actor object
         * there is an actor table that controls entry space. In occurrences of other actors , 
         * the object is altered, other than that 
         * objected is created and appended to the table
         * @param stringTokenizer makes the text file divided into individual components
         */
        public void assemblyLines(String[] stringTokenizer){
                Film film = new Film(stringTokenizer[0]);

                for(int i = 1; i < stringTokenizer.length;i++){

                        Actor actor;
                        String actorName = stringTokenizer[i];

                        if(actors.containsKey(actorName)){                        
                                actor = actors.get(actorName);
                        } else {
                                actor = new Actor(actorName);
                                actors.put(actorName, actor);
                        }
                        film.addActor(actor);
                        actor.addFilm(film);
                }
        }        

}
```